# Yehei Shmei Rabbah... Yisbarach

Tags: minhag, kaddish

Not sure where it came from, but many people tend to say Yisbarach after the Amen Yehei Shmei Rabbah verse. Where did this come from? Is this correct?

Comment: In Karlin they say up till Damiran Balma

Comment: @GershonGold This is the minhag of the Sephardim as well -- to say the 28 (Gematria כח, strength) words starting at Y'hei Sh'mei. The last of those 28 words is "b'alma".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question should be the other way around.  The Mechaber (O.C. 56:3) says it is forbidden for the answerer to interrupt between almaya and yisbarach.

The Magen Avraham writes that the implication of the Bais Yosef is like Gershon wrote, but sides with the old custom of stopping given the importance of listening to the chazan specifically.

Our minhag is like the GRA to only go up to almaya to get 28 letters, not necessarily because yisbarach is separate.  Although our nusach which has yishtabach with a vav seems to indicate that yisbarach is separate.

Comment: 28 letters ends *before* the word Yitbarach. Count it yourself: יְהֵא שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא מְבָרַךְ. לְעָלַם וּלְעָלְמֵי עָלְמַיָּא

Comment: Right, that's the rationale to stop at almaya.

Comment: Ive heard that the Ari says to go up to 'brich hu"

Comment: Any reason for that?

Comment: @BaalShemotTovot Courtesy Ping. And I second YDK's question.